# How to add subheadings to x-axis of bar plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bar plot that I've made in ggplot2, but I'd like to annotated the x-axis further. I want to cluster these groups together into transformation groups (similar to the graph you can see made in excel). How can I go about doing this with ggplot2?

Here's the code that I used.

```
DNAngPERuL <- 160
DNAug <- DNAngPERuL * 6 / 1000
colony_data_frequency <- colony_data / DNAug

transf_data <- data.frame(Selection=rep(c('Ntc 200 μg/mL', 'Zeo 25 μg/mL'), each=12),
                 biorep=rep(c('1', '1(-ve)', '2', '2(-ve)', '3', '3(-ve)', '4', '4(-ve)', '5', '5(-ve)', '6', '6(-ve)'), times=2),
                 colonies=colony_data_frequency)

# Plot
ggplot(data=transf_data, aes(fill=Selection, x=biorep, y=colonies)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat="identity", colour="#434343", linetype = "solid") + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(title="Transformation Frequency", x="Bioreplicate", y = "No. of colonies / μg of DNA") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#3288bd", "#66C2A5")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .1)))
```

[image: ggplot2]

[image]

Comment: It can be done using `facet` and some manual adjustment to your xAxis tick ;)

Answer (score 1):

Key here is indeed faceting, though when you just apply facets for the first time it might not be so obvious how to move towards that end goal as you probably need to re-arrange aesthetics a bit first.

Here's a generic example with iris dataset, split into 3 steps:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# prepare example dataset suitable for identity stat
iris_summary <- iris %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean), .by = Species) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Sepal"), names_to = "Measure")
iris_summary
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   Species    Measure      value
#>   <fct>      <chr>        <dbl>
#> 1 setosa     Sepal.Length  5.01
#> 2 setosa     Sepal.Width   3.43
#> 3 versicolor Sepal.Length  5.94
#> 4 versicolor Sepal.Width   2.77
#> 5 virginica  Sepal.Length  6.59
#> 6 virginica  Sepal.Width   2.97
```

```r
# starting point, grouped by Species on x-axis
ggplot(iris_summary, aes(fill = Measure, x = Species, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

```r
# moving from Species groups on x-axis to facet by Species,
# note how aes() is changed
ggplot(iris_summary, aes(fill = Measure, x = Measure, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~ Species)
```

[image]

```r
# adjust strip location (facet labels) and theme, 
# with facet labels at the bottom the x title would also be out of place
ggplot(iris_summary, aes(fill = Measure, x = Measure, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(
    # axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = .5),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside", 
    strip.background.x = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title = element_blank()
    )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>